# How to compare all the columns of a dataframe with another dataframe columns and obtain delta

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have 2 folders containing some 500 txt files each. The file names are same in both the folders. I need to compare each column from each file from one folder with another folder file and find the delta if any. The column count may be more than 100 in some files. What is the best way to calculate the delta from all the files?
I have tried various approaches like df1[col].equals(df2[col]) but while executing a larger file, dtype memory expection comes and execution stops abruptly.

I have tried the following sequence:
1) Loop through the files in the folder.
2) Put folder1-filex into one dataframe(df1) and folder2-filex into another dataframe(df2).
3) loop through all the columns to find the difference using 
if not df1[col].equals(df2[col]):
     compare()#shown below
4) Append the result to a new Dataframe

```
def compare():
   df1= pd.read_csv(folder1_xfile.txt,sep='\t')
   df2= pd.read_csv(folder2_xfile.txt,sep='\t')
   ser1= pd.Series(df1[col].to_list())
   ser2= pd.Series(df2[col].to_list())
   d2= ser1.eq(ser2)
   changeRow= d2.index.where(d2==False).fillna(9999999)
```

'''
    From the above I can get the row index where there is a value change.
    But for huge data, this condition is failing and the execution stops 
    abruptly.
   '''

```
def getComparison(df1,df2,fi):

    changeVla=[]
    dfold= pd.DataFrame()
    df= pd.DataFrame()

    for col in df2.columns:
        if not df1[col].equals(df2[col]):
            ser1= pd.Series(df1[col].to_list())
            ser2= pd.Series(df2[col].to_list())

            d2= ser1.eq(ser2)

            changeVla= d2.index.where(d2==False).fillna(9999999)




Final_dataframe= [file_name   Difference_Column_name  
     folder1_file_column_value   folder2_file_column_value]
```

Actual Result: Execution failing all of a sudden (Mostly due to memory).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```py
compare = pd.concat([df1, df2], sort=False)
duped = compare[compare.duplicated()]
```

Not sure how well it will do on memory.